# Possible to change GitBash color scheme on Windows 10 without Windows Terminal?

Tags: windows-10, git-bash

I'm using Windows 10 and have installed GitBash.  I would like to change the background and foreground colors.  However, I don't have permissions to install Windows Terminal, which can streamline the process (so I'm told) of changing the color scheme.

How, if possible, can I change the color scheme of GitBash on Windows 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right click on the top bar of a git bash terminal a menu will come up, then select options. It should take you to the looks tab which will allow you to change the colors of foreground & background.

[image]

Comment: "right click on the top bar of a git bash terminal" helped me

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at ConEmu terminal emulator for Windows, it has portable version which doesn't require install:

https://conemu.github.io/

https://www.fosshub.com/ConEmu.html

It can be highly customized and also has many predefined color themes.

Comment: Hi Intruder, a question for you. Are you associated with it in any way ?

Comment: You mean with ConEmu? No, I'm not. I just know that tool exists.

Answer (score 1):

Open gitbash and do the next: you can set colors inside the conf file used by gitbash .mynttyrc

```
cd ~
notepad.exe .minttyrc
```

Then set the conf as needed:

```
# Example .minttyrc
# Background color
BackgroundColour=150,150,255
# Text color
Black=0,0,0
BoldBlack=128,128,128
# Cursor color
CursorColour=2,2,2
# Font settings (change these to match your preference)
Font=Consolas
FontHeight=14
```

Once this is done, save and close notepad. Then close gitbash and open it again. Et voila!

Answer (score 1):

From the post
[How to change RGB colors in Git Bash for windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243172/how-to-change-rgb-colors-in-git-bash-for-windows)
I quote the accepted answer:

> - Click on the upper left corner of an open Git Bash window (the Git icon in the window frame).
> - A menu appears (the same that would appear with a regular DOS cmd Window). Choose the last entry: "Properties", UPDATE 2021:
>   "Options..." (thanks AlexD!)
> - Go to tab "Colors"
> - Choose radio button "Screen Text"
> - Remember which color is currently assigned to "Screen Text" in the row of small color boxes (it has a black frame).
> - Then select the color you want to change by clicking on the corresponding color box. This color is now assigned as "Screen Text",
>   which is what Git Bash uses for regular text. But don't worry, this
>   change is only temporary and needed to modify the value of a color.
> - Now change the Red/Green/Blue values for the selected color. In my case I wanted to make the fifth color from the left (much) brighter.
>   Let's call it "Color 5". This is the color Git Bash uses to show
>   changed files with "git status". Whenever Git Bash wants to use "Color
>   5" it will use the new RGB value.
> - "Screen Text" is now still set to "Color 5". So click on the original color that you have remembered.
>
> The changes made in this way are permanent but only valid for the
> shortcut you have used to start Git Bash. If you create a new shortcut
> you are back to the original colors.

Another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44011634/165358)
shows how to change the colors in the configuration file
`%USERPROFILE%\.minttyrc` (may be different for other releases).

Still another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40010276/165358)
advises to add to the end of
`C:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile.d\git-prompt.sh`
the line:

```
LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'di=1;30:' ; export LS_COLORS
```

Still another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49484499/165358)
notes that Git bash uses the default Windows console colors,
which may be tweaked in the registry at
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console`.

More answers add more methods. Not all methods are valid for
all releases of Git bash.